# Problem passing a value from one PHP page to another

Tags: php

I'm quite new to this, but I'll try my best to explain my problem as clearly as I can. I have two files - one called `edit_captions_form.php` which contains a class called edit_form which sets out the elements that are to be part of the form. The number of elements is decided dynamically and they are added from a database using a loop. The loop counter is the number of rows returned from the sql query and is passed in the url. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
class edit_form extends moodleform {

function definition() {

    $numRows = $_GET['numRows'];


    if(isset($numRows)){
        echo "yes" .$numRows;  }
        else
            echo "no";
//result: yes and the value of $numRows


    $mform = & $this->_form;
              .
             //some irrelevant code
              .

    $mform->addElement('header', 'editcaptionsheader', $editcaptionsheader .$title);
               .
              //some more irrelevant code
               .
    $captionResult = mysql_query($captionQuery);
    $captionsArray = array();

    $textFieldAttributes = "size=\"10\" value=\"\"";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($captionResult)) {
        array_push($captionsArray, $row);


    }


    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {

        $startName = "start_" . $i;
        $startValue = $captionsArray[$i]['start_time'];
        $endName = "end_" . $i;
        $endValue = $captionsArray[$i]['end_time'];
        $captionName = "caption_" . $i;
        $captionValue = $captionsArray[$i]['caption_text'];
        $captionIdName = "id_".$i;
        $captionIdValue = $captionsArray[$i]['caption_id'];


        //  print_object($captionsArray);


        $mform->addElement('hidden', $captionIdName, $captionIdResult);
        $mform->addElement('text', $startName, $editstarttimeTrans, $textFieldAttributes);

        $mform->setDefault($startName, $startValue);
        $mform->addElement('text', $endName, $editendtimeTrans, $textFieldAttributes);
        $mform->setDefault($endName, $endValue);


        //text area to contain caption text
        $mform->addElement('htmleditor', $captionName, "$editcaptiontextTrans: ", 'wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"');
        $mform->setDefault($captionName, $captionValue);

        //echo "<button type = \"button\", name = \"edit_caption\", onclick = 'updateRecordInDatabase($referenceId, $start, $end, $text)'>Save</button>";
      $buttonarray = array();
      $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('submit', 'submitbutton', get_string('savechanges'));
      $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('reset', 'resetbutton', get_string('revert'));
      $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('cancel');
    //add_action_buttons($buttonarray[0] = true);
      $mform->addGroup($buttonarray, 'buttonar', '', array(' '), false);
      $mform->closeHeaderBefore('buttonar');
```

The second file is called `edit_captions.php` and creates an instance of `edit_form` and tries to extract the values from the form elements and again uses a loop with a counter derived from the number of rows. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
require_once("edit_captions_form.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];
$numRows = $_GET['numRows'];

echo " the number of rows: " .$numRows;
//$numRows doesn't print here

$pageForm = new edit_form();

if($pageForm->is_cancelled())
{
 redirect elsewhere

}

 else if($fromform = $pageForm->get_data())
{


 for ($i=0; $i<$numRows; $i++)
{
 $elementNumber = 3+(5*$i);//3, 8, 13, 18

 $elementArray = $pageForm->_form->_elements;
 $timeAtts = $elementArray[$elementNumber]->_attributes;
 $captionStartTime = $timeAtts['value'];
 $elementNumber = $elementNumber +1;

 $elementArray = $pageForm->_form->_elements;
 $endTimeAtts = $elementArray[$elementNumber]->_attributes;
 $captionEndTime = $endTimeAtts['value'];
 $elementNumber = $elementNumber +1;

 $elementArray =$pageForm->_form->_elements;
 $captionText = $elementArray[$elementNumber]->_value;

}
```

Now, if I hardcode in the actual number of rows as a counter for both loops, the value of all the array elements are stored in `$elementArray` and can be retrieved, so everything is ok in that regard. The problem is that no matter what I do there is no value in the $numRows variable in the `edit_captions.php` file so the loop doesn't execute I can't get the data.

I thought I would have access to this because I've used `require_once(edit_captions_form.php)` I tried getting the value from a function using a MySQL query instead of through `$_GET`, I tried magic methods `__set()` and `__get()`, though I didn't really understand what I was doing so that could be why that didn't work, I tried to access `$numRows` as if it were a variable of the `edit_form` class, though I don't think it is because it's in function definition(). I tried adding it as a variable before definition() but that broke the whole form. I also tried using the `global` keyword but that didn't work either.

Again, apologies if I'm not explaining this very well but I can't think of a more concise way to state the problem. I've been trying to sort this out for three days solid and haven't been able to do it. I would appreciate it if anyone could please explain to me why I can't access `$numRows` for the loop in the second file. Or if it's just not possible, please put my out of my misery and let me know!

Comment: Where your code says `echo " the number of rows: " .$numRows; //$numRows doesn't print here` does that mean you get no output at all or just nothing in the `$numRows` variable? What's the exact URL including parameters displayed when this happens?

Comment: Hi Simon, sorry that is a bit misleading and I meant to add more detail before I posted the question. When the form is displayed, the echo statement prints fine and the url is edit_captions.php?id=7&numRows=8. However, when I click the 'save changes' button the page redirects for a few seconds to another page that just informs the user that editing is complete before redirecting to another page. The url on the edit complete page is edit_captions.php and on this page it prints out "the number of rows: " but with nothing in the $numRows variable. I hope this is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the "another page that informs".

It is not passing the GET variables to the edit_captions.php so there is nothing it can access :)

Comment: Thanks McKracken - that makes sense, I was kind of ignoring that page. I'll see if I can do something about that.

Comment: I got rid of the other page and also put a hidden element on the form with the row number to pass to the other file and tested that both forms have the same value and they so some problems are solved and I wanted to say thanks for that. Still haven't got it working yet but I think I'm a bit closer.